# Configuring an MSI file to launch and kill a program upon installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have an application I've developed in Visual Studio 2010 and need to configure the installer (as a .msi file) to launch the program and then kill the task. I have a custom action in the msi to launch the program, but I'm having trouble adding a step to kill the task as well. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Comment: If you've got code in your custom action that isn't working, then you show the code. That's not really a windows installer issue AFAIK.

Comment: There is no code, on the commit node right now I have it running the primary output. No custom code behind it. I'm asking if there's a way to have the application launch and then close as part of the installation.

Comment: If you launch the process as commit custom action in an Everyone install, there are two issues. 1) It will run with the system account and be unable to access the desktop and other user profile items, possibly failing and 2) The installation will pause until the process finishes. It's still not clear to me what "kill" means in your question because it implies that you launch your program with your code, so why doesn't it just finish?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom action in order to handle this. Windows Installer doesn't have a kill process event. Below is a native C++ app that I created to handle this.

```
// KillProc.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

BOOL KillProcess(_TCHAR* szProcessToKill);
TCHAR* AcTcharlower(TCHAR *pString);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    if(argc > 1){
        KillProcess(argv[1]);
    }else{
        // No Process found
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL KillProcess(_TCHAR* szProcessToKill){
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry32;
    LPWSTR lpszBuffer = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
    LPWSTR lpszProcessToKill = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
    lpszProcessToKill = AcTcharlower(szProcessToKill);
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);  // Takes a snapshot of all the processes
    if(hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        return( FALSE );
    }

    processEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if(!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &processEntry32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);     
        return( FALSE );
    }

    do
    {
        lpszBuffer = processEntry32.szExeFile;
        if(!wcsicmp(lpszBuffer,szProcessToKill)){    // Is this our Process
            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,0, processEntry32.th32ProcessID);  // It is so get the process handle
            TerminateProcess(hProcess,0);
            CloseHandle(hProcess); 
        } 
    }while(Process32Next(hProcessSnap,&processEntry32));  // gets next member of snapshot

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);  // closes the snapshot handle
    return( TRUE );
}

TCHAR* AcTcharlower(TCHAR *pString)
{
    static TCHAR pBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR *s = pString;
    TCHAR *t = pBuffer;
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        *t = tolower(*s);
        s++;
        t++;
    }
    return(pBuffer);
}
```